# Installing PHP+Apache on Windows Server with IIS+PHP simultaneously?

Tags: windows, php, apache-http-server, windows-server-2008, iis

I'm working for a client who rents a dedicated server running Windows Server 2008 (I'm almost certain) and has someone they know managing the server. We've built a new site built in WordPress MU and Magento which is a pain to install on IIS when I can't access the server configuration.

We've asked the admin to install Apache on the server simultaneously, running on a different port at first until we confirm everything is alright. The thing is, he has said that PHP can only be installed for either IIS or Apache and not both. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not right. You should have separate installations of PHP for IIS and Apache so that configuration files can be adjusted for each one.

You can have completely separate installations of PHP running for each server.  In fact, there are packages you can download that have Apache+PHP+MySQL pre-packaged and ready to go.  I recommend [XMAPP](http://apachefriends.org).  That would allow you to setup a separate Apache+PHP stack to use, as you said, with a different port running.  You could even configure IIS or apache to act as a reverse proxy to have a certain URL point to the other server.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's what I was thinking. The admin has been a bit of a pain from day 1 though, I guess he wants to regain full control. Tricky politics!

Thanks again mate.